# Getting Wrong Value Parsing XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

Environment:  VS 2010, .NET 3.5

I'm working on a project that pulls data from a RESTful web service.  Almost all of it is working correctly except one section where it's getting incorrect values.

Here's a sample of the XML used in this part of the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<dataprovider>
  <id>DP6</id>
  <name>Query 1</name>
  <dataSourceId>96390</dataSourceId>
  <dataSourcePrefix>DS6</dataSourcePrefix>
  <updated>2014-08-25T16:51:38.000-04:00</updated>
  <duration>1</duration>
  <isPartial>false</isPartial>
  <rowCount>13</rowCount>
  <flowCount>1</flowCount>
  <dictionary>
    <expression qualification="Dimension" dataType="String">
      <id>DP6.DOa6</id>
      <name>City</name>
      <description>City located.</description>
      <dataSourceObjectId>DS6.DOa6</dataSourceObjectId>
      <formulaLanguageId>[City]</formulaLanguageId>
    </expression>
  </dictionary>
</dataprovider>
```

And here is the code:

```
private void loadElements(List<string> dps, int rptId)
{
  string name = string.Empty;
  string id = string.Empty;
  string elementUrl = baseUrl + string.Format(C_WEBI_URL, rptId) + C_DP_URL;
  foreach (string dpId in dps)
  {
    XmlDocument dpXml = getResponse(elementUrl + "/" + dpId);
    //get the Expression nodes that define the objects on the report
    XmlNodeList elementNodes = dpXml.SelectNodes("//expression");
    if (elementNodes != null)
    {
      foreach (XmlNode node in elementNodes)
      {
        id = node.SelectSingleNode("//dataSourceObjectId").InnerText;
        if (!elements.ContainsKey(id))
        {
          name = node.SelectSingleNode("//name").InnerText;
          elements.Add(id, name);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I expect to get a value of "DP6.DOa6" from the dataSourceObjectId, but it returns just "DP6".  And I expect to get a value of "City" from the name, but it returns "Query 1".  When I test the XPath with the above XML at http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath, I get the correct values, but it's not working in my code.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The problem with your name query is that the XmlNode object retains the outer xml as well so when you say `//name` it will return the first name element it finds in the document. I cannot find an example of how to do that properly right now otherwise I would post an answer.

Comment: As to the dataSourceObjectId my suspicion is that the `.` is causing this behavior perhaps try `InnerXml` instead of `InnerText`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your name query is that the XmlNode object retains the outer xml as well so when you say `//name` it will return the first name element it finds in the document.

The correct xpath syntax will be `name` (no slashes).

As to the `dataSourceObjectId` my suspicion is that the `.` is causing this behavior perhaps try `InnerXml` instead of `InnerText`

Complete example:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in elementNodes)
  {
    id = node.SelectSingleNode("dataSourceObjectId").InnerXml; //I'm not sure if this will solve the problem.
    if (!elements.ContainsKey(id))
    {
      name = node.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText;
      elements.Add(id, name);
    }
  }
```